# Ruby on Rails: Using devise, auto-create profile with user, in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a RoR question, though it is pretty easy, I just can't do it.

Here it goes.

I have a User model created using devise. I also want to create a Profile model using scaffold, and associate it with User.

Now, I want to create Profile entry whenever one created an account using devise. This is how I would do it:

```
user.rb
has_one :profile
before_create :build_profile
```

Then this is my profile model

```
profile.rb
belongs_to :user
```

My schema for profile only has:

```
[username | organization | bio | birth date | gender | created_at | updated_at]
```

Now, when the devise user_signup route is invoked, there is only email, password, and password confirmation.

What I wanted was to include all the Profile schema along side with the devise User creation page (form).

Is there anyway I can achieve that? If Rails can't do that, is there a way that I can redirect the user when he created an account, to be redirected to profile creation page (and possibly not let him access other functions until he filled up the profile page)?

P.S. I am just starting RoR developing and don't know how to approach this problem.

If you could have any code snippets for me, that would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: https://gorails.com/forum/create-a-user-profile-after-saving-a-devise-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `belongs_to` and `has_one` are ActiveRecord helpers, that allow you to easily call related Models. But you have to create foreign keys yourself, in this case a user_id on Profile for User, so your Profile schema will look like:

```
[username | organization | bio | birth date | gender | user_id | created_at | updated_at]
```

After you've connected `Profile` to `User`, if you want them to fill out Profile information, you do need to redirect them to a `Profile#edit` view, where they'll add all these extra fields, which will get saved into Profile. You can also do it as part of User sign_up form itself, it's up to you.

To enable custom views with Devise, so you can add extra fields on your sign_up form and then assign them to Profile, you need to set `config.scoped_views = true` inside the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.

After that you can write completely custom view for example in `users/sessions/new`, depending on the role. Just add extra fields and then assign them to Profile in again custom Devise controller, say `Users::SessionsController`. For more details just check instructions on views [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views) and on controllers [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers).

You can make custom redirects for Devise on ApplicationController. You can read more on Devise [wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration))

Comment: the one i'm not familiar with is how could I make it a part of User sign_up form itself, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Lorelyn You can find that information on Devise -> https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Comment: I've updated my answer @Lorelyn, but again you can find all that information on Devise Getting Started...